# Can Unity be configured to load and unload modules at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Currently I am using Unity to resolve types at run time.

```
IUnityContainer _container = new UnityContainer();
_container.LoadConfiguration();

var instance = _container.Resolve<IGenericLib>("Class1");

instance.DoSomething();
```

So , I am just reolving Class1 at the moment , though I have total three types , defined in config section.

```
<unity>
    <namespace name="GenricType.Interface"/>
    <namespace name="Sample.Type1"/>
    <namespace name="Sample.Type2"/>
    <namespace name="Sample.Type3"/>
    <assembly name="GenricType.Interface"/>
    <assembly name="Sample.Type1"/>
    <assembly name="Sample.Type2"/>
    <assembly name="Sample.Type3"/>
    <container>
      <register type="IGenericLib" mapTo="Class1" name="Class1"/>
      <register type="IGenericLib" mapTo="Class2" name="Class2"/>
      <register type="IGenericLib" mapTo="Class3" name="Class3"/>
    </container>
  </unity>
```

Now I am setting a break point to look at the modules loaded and here are the snapshots.

Before I call Load Configuration, none of my aseemblies are loaded to memory ,

[image]

But the moment load configuration is called , all three of my assmbly are loaded , though I am just reolving Class1.

[image]

Is there a way I could control loading of these modules?Just the load the module that is currently resolved and unload after use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadContainer()` loads all configured modules. In `<container>` section you have three modules so unity loads all three. Resolving is just taking an instance of already loaded modules. To control what modules you want to load you can use overload method:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
    .LoadConfiguration("Class1");
```

You can also load modules from different section:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
    .LoadConfiguration(section)  // Loads unnamed <container> element
    .LoadConfiguration(section, "otherContainerElement"); // named <container> element
```

Comment: Thansk , and Is there a way I can unload them after using